# RDS, RDWeb, and RemoteApp: How to use public certificate for launching apps on session host?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, rdp, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

**Question:**
How do i tell RDWeb to launch apps from remote.domain.com rather then host.internaldomain.local?

**Environment:**

Existing org with AD forest. New single Server 2012 running all Remote Desktop Services roles for session host. Used the new 2012 wizard to setup "QuickSessionCollection" with roles:

- RD Session Host
- RD Connection Broker
- RD Gateway
- RD Web Access
- RD Licensing

Everything works with self-signed cert, but we want to prevent those.

The users are potentially non-domain machines so sticking a private root cert for on their machines isn't an option. Every part of the solution needs to use public cert.

Added public remote.domain.com cert to all roles using Server Manager GUI:

- RD Connection Broker - Enable Single Sign On
- RD Connection Broker - Publishing
- RD Web Access
- RD Gateway

So now everything works beautifully except the last step:

1. user logs into https://remote.domain.com
2. user clicks a app icon, which in background downloads a .rdp file that is signed by remote.domain.com.
3. .rdp is set to use RD Gateway, which is remote.domain.com
4. .rdp says app is hosted on internal host.internaldomain.local, which doesn't match the RDP-tcp TLS cert of remote.domain.com, and pops a warning.

It's this last step that I'd like to fix. Is there a config option in PowerShell, WMI, or .config to tell RDWeb/RemoteApp to use remote.domain.com for all published apps so the TLS cert for RDP matches what the Session Host is using?

NOTE: [This question talks about this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/52701/certificate-issue-with-remoteapp-on-server-2008), and [this answer mentions how you might fix](https://serverfault.com/a/164439/51031) it in 2008, but that GUI doesn't exist in 2012 for RemoteApp, and I can't find a PowerShell setting for it.

NOTE: Here's a screenshot of the setting in 2008R2 that I need to change. It tells RemoteApp what to use for the Session Host server name. How can I set that in 2012?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This PowerShell worked: tell the Session Collection to add a alternate address for Session Host connections. This is also what you would do for a Session Host farm with round robin.

Once I ran this, launching apps from RDWeb would give a single prompt that now matches the three settings without warnings:

- Publisher: remote.domain.com
- **Remote computer: remote.domain.com**
- Gateway server: remote.domain.com

> Set-RDSessionCollectionConfiguration –CollectionName QuickSessionCollection -CustomRdpProperty "use redirection server name:i:1 `n alternate full address:s:remote.domain.com"

Depending on any other Custom RDP Properties, the above command may be different because you have to include them all in one command with a linefeed between each.

Background Info:

Adding custom RDP settings: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15719.adding-custom-rdp-properties-in-windows-server-2012-vdi-rds-environments.aspx

Using this setting for HA: http://microsoftplatform.blogspot.com/2012/04/rd-connection-broker-ha-and-rdp.html

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that you need a cert valid for both the internal and external namespace. If you have .local internally (yuck) then you may have a hard time acquiring a cert with .local in either the Subject or Subject Alternative Name fields. If you can't get a cert from a public provider for this, then an internal PKI setup is your only option here.

Comment: Right, the assumption is I won't use a .local cert at all. This was possible in 2008R2 based on my screenshot above, but that was before Connection Brokers were required and the `RemoteApp Manager` GUI was removed. So, this should work fine with a non-hostname for RD Session Host, just need to find where 2012 expects us to set the setting above.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a UC certificate you can use this powershell script to update the FQDN to match your external host name / certificate name:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Change-published-FQDN-for-2a029b80

Comment: I've read that this script can cause errors in RDS. "Please note that there are issues using RD Web feed after using this to change the client access name. RDS looks for a RDCB farm during the connection process and then fails." This tells me that this method is unsupported by Microsoft. Is there an alternative way to change the name that is supported? source: http://ryanmangansitblog.com/2013/03/10/configuring-rds-2012-certificates-and-sso/ under "Certificate Mismatches".